# Get statistics from pandas dataframe: unique fields by date

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to calculate how many urls verified are in a dataset.

```py
       Date                   Urls  Verified
 12/03/2020  www.stackoverflow.com      True
 12/03/2020         www.google.com      True
 12/03/2020        www.youtube.com      True
 12/03/2020         www.bients.com     False
 13/03/2020         www.google.com      True
 13/03/2020         www.amazon.com      True
 14/03/2020         www.bients.com     False
 14/03/2020   www.Breaking-CNN.com     False
```

and so on.

I would like to get:

- the number of verified urls (Verified = True) by date;
- the total number of verified urls.

However, I would need to remove duplicates from counting. 
My expected output would be:

```
12/03/2020 Verified: 3
           Not Verified: 1
13/03/2020 Verified: 2
           Not Verified: 0
14/03/2020 Verified: 0
           Not Verified: 2
```

Total Verified: 4 (I should avoid duplicates such as www.google.com or www.bients.com)
Total Unverified: 2

How could I get these results? I think using unique and groupby but I have not understood the order.

Comment: `df.groupby(['Date', 'Verified']).agg({'Verified': 'count'})`

Comment: Have a look at [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) for the first part.  To remove duplicates you could create a separate data frame that has URL as the index or do a groupby URL. Try out some code and post it in your question if you need more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `drop_duplicates`, the `groupby` + `value_counts`

```
s=df.drop_duplicates().groupby('Date').Verified.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
Date        Verified
12/03/2020  False       1
            True        3
13/03/2020  False       0
            True        2
14/03/2020  False       2
            True        0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you @YOBEN_S. In case the field Verified would be empty, would I get an error because of that? I got the following error: `IndexError: list index out of range`, and I think it is because some fields are empty. Might it be the case? Thanks

Comment: @still_learning yes, that is the reason , drop the empty first ~

Comment: Thank you so much. Another question, if I may. In case I had more columns, for example date, urls, verified, country,... in order to keep only unique urls, should I still use the fields as in your code, or should I consider something different?

Comment: @still_learning pass subset in drop_duplciate like subset=['Date',                   'Urls ', 'Verified']

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
df2=df.groupby(['Date']).Verified.value_counts().unstack('Date').fillna(0).T.reset_index()
df2.columns=['Date','Unverified','verified']
```

[image]